# A teacher divides seven girls and five boys randomly into three groups of four each. What is the probability that one group has four girls?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Question in title. Sorry, this is my first question and I don't know how to format.

My thinking was 
$$\frac{3\binom{7}{4}\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}}{\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}}.$$
 The numerator comes from 3 groups to put four girls into, and $\binom{7}{4}$ ways to choose those girls. Once that group is set, there are $\binom{8}{4}$ to put kids into the second group and $\binom{4}{4}$ ways to put kids into the third group.

That gives me an answer of $7/132$ but the book I'm using says the answer is $7/33$. Can you please help me find what I'm missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your method of solution is indeed correct.  Check your arithmetic.

$$\frac{3\cdot \binom{7}{4} \binom{8}{4} \binom{4}{4}}{\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}} = \frac{3\cdot \binom{7}{4}}{\binom{12}{4}}=\frac{3\cdot 35}{495}=\frac{7}{33}$$